# Does a method used in main method need its own class?

Tags: java, class, methods

I am writing a code that checks password entries. The main method checks a secondary method and outputs a line depending on whether it's true or false. My problem is when I compile it gives expected class error for the second method, but if I try to use the same class as my main it gives duplicate class error. I didn't think I needed a second class. Anyone care to help me out?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CheckPassword {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a password");
        password = input.nextLine();
        if (check(password)) {
           System.out.println("Valid Password");
        }
        else{
           System.out.println("Invalid Password");
        }
    }
}

public class CheckPassword {
    public static boolean check(String password) {
        boolean check = true;
        if(password.length() < 8) {
            check = false;
        }
        int num = 0;
        for(int x = 0; x < password.length(); x++) {
            if(isLetter(password.charAt(x)) || isDigit(password.charAt(x))){
                if(isDigit(password.charAt(x))){
                    num++;
                    if (num >=2){
                        check = true;    
                    } 
                    else{
                        check = false;
                    }
               }
           }
       }
    }  
}
```

Comment: Don't declare the class twice

Comment: You have two public class in a same file named the same. This is two mistake in a java file

Comment: Stick to just one class when you start to learn java. When you learn about object oriented programming you can start to play around with classes.

Comment: so, you think you don't need two classes, hence you define two classes? the problem is not as much that you have two classes, it's that you have two classes in the same package with the same name and on the same level. And, most likely, that you have two public (non-static) classes in the same file.

Comment: if i dont have a second class it gives me an error " class, interface, or enum expected."  thats why i figured i would try adding it.

Comment: i see what i did wrong, i didnt realize i closed the main method before continuing

Comment: Please learn the very basics of the technology you are using before you post about it to SO.

Answer (score -1):

No need another class, but needed to static import isDigit and isLetter. I fixed your code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

import static java.lang.Character.isDigit;
import static java.lang.Character.isLetter;

public class CheckPassword {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a password");
        String password = input.nextLine();
        if (check(password)) {
            System.out.println("Valid Password");
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Invalid Password");
        }
    }

    public static boolean check(String password) {
        boolean check = true;
        if(password.length() < 8) {
            check = false;
        }
        int num = 0;
        for(int x = 0; x < password.length(); x++) {
            if(isLetter(password.charAt(x)) || isDigit(password.charAt(x))){
                if(isDigit(password.charAt(x))){
                    num++;
                    if (num >=2){
                        check = true;
                    }
                    else{
                        check = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return check;
    }
}
```